# Grouping a pivot table different range

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table. I want to group this pivot different range. How can i achieve this?

pivot image

[image: pi]

wanted pivot

[image]
I am trying this code:

```
wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
ws = GetWorksheet(Handle, Workbook, Worksheet)
wb.Activate()
ws.Activate()
excel = ws.Application
sheet = excel.ActiveSheet
pvt = ws.PivotTables(myPTN)
pvt.LabelRange.Group(Start:=2, By:=7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved!

```
Dim wb, ws, excel, sheet As Object 
wb = GetWorkbook(Handle, Workbook)
ws = GetWorksheet(Handle, Workbook, Worksheet)

wb.Activate()
ws.Activate()
excel = ws.Application
sheet = excel.ActiveSheet

ws.PivotTables(myPTN).PivotFields(myField).DataRange.Cells(1,1).Group(Start:=True, End:=True, By:=myRange)
```